# Can Azure durable function be stop by external event?

Tags: azure, azure-durable-functions

We are trying to see if Durable function can replace Siebel has our Workflow orchestrator. Most of my questions were answer by the online doc, but one remain.

Can it be stop by and external events and put to wait? In our case our workflow doesn’t know that another WF can stop it. So we can’t use “waitForExternalEvent”.

Let’s say WF A is running and the client launch WF B.

B need to put A in a wait state until it’s completed.

So the question is : is it possible to do so with durable functions in some way ?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You can create HTTP triggers that interact with your durable functions and use standard REST semantics.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and in fact there's such pattern "External Event":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-external-events?tabs=csharp

Comment: I’ve read that article already and I’m not sure to understand. The WF A is not waiting for anything... does it mean we will have to implement WaitForExternalEvent and check if an event is raise? Cause in our wf it doesn’t mean they will be stop by WF B all the time. Most of the time it continues till the end ...

Comment: if you scroll down, You'll see a POST approving:

Comment: POST /runtime/webhooks/durabletask/instances/MyInstanceId/raiseEvent/Approval&code=XXX
Content-Type: application/json

"true"

Comment: so it will await until the external event happens. You can also specify a "cancelation" e.g. if nothing happens in 48 hours, discard the await...

Comment: Ok I’ll look at it with our dev team to see if this could work for us! Thank you for your help!